# How does take(2) operator works

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm currently working on an Angular application where I encountered an issue related to the take(2) operator. I'm using it in combination with navigation using the Angular Router, and I noticed that the navigation only works on the second call. I'm seeking help to understand the behavior of the take(2) operator and why this navigation issue occurs.

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm working with:

The resolver component where I call the fetchRecipes method:

```
 export class RecipesResolverService implements Resolve<Recipe[]> {



constructor(private dataStorageService: DataStorageService, private recipesService: RecipeService) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const recipes = this.recipesService.getRecipes()

    if (recipes.length === 0) {
      return this.dataStorageService.fetchRecipes()
    } else {
      return recipes
    }
  }
}
```

The part of the `dataStorageService` where I fetch the recipes:

```
fetchRecipes() {
        return this.authService.user.pipe(
            take(2),
            exhaustMap((user) => {
        console.log('EXHAUST MAP')
        console.log(user)
                return this.http.get<Recipe[]>(environment.firebaseRealTimeDatabaseUrl + '/recipes.json', {
                    params: new HttpParams().set('auth', user.token)
                });
            }),
            map((recipes) => {
                return recipes.map((recipe) => {
                    return { ...recipe, ingredients: recipe.ingredients ? recipe.ingredients : [] };
                });
            }),
            tap((recipes) => {
                this.recipeService.setRecipes(recipes);
            })
        );
    }
```

The user is a BehaviorSubject which gets called in the auth service on the login or sign-up method.

```
export interface AuthResponseData {
    kind: string;
    idToken: string;
    email: string;
    refreshToken: string;
    expiresIn: string;
    localId: string;
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
    user: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

signUp(email: string, password: string): Observable<AuthResponseData | string> {
    return this.http
        .post<
            AuthResponseData
        >(`https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=${environment.API_KEY}`, {
            email: email,
            password: password,
            returnSecureToken: true
        })
        .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError),
            tap((resData) => {
                if (typeof resData === 'string') {
                    return;
                }

                this.handleAuthentication(resData.email, resData.localId, resData.idToken, +resData.expiresIn);
            })
        );
}

login(email: string, password: string): Observable<AuthResponseData | string> {
    return this.http
        .post<
            AuthResponseData
        >(`https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=${environment.API_KEY}`, {
            email: email,
            password: password,
            returnSecureToken: true
        })
        .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError),
            tap((resData) => {
                if (typeof resData === 'string') {
                    return;
                }

                this.handleAuthentication(resData.email, resData.localId, resData.idToken, +resData.expiresIn);
            })
        );
}

private handleError(errorRes: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = 'An unknown error occurred!';

    if (!errorRes.error || !errorRes.error.error) return errorMessage;

    switch (errorRes.error.error.message) {
        case 'EMAIL_EXISTS':
            errorMessage = 'This email exists already!';
            break;
        case 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND':
            errorMessage = 'This email does not exist!';
            break;
        case 'INVALID_PASSWORD':
            errorMessage = 'This password is not correct!';
            break;
    }

    return throwError(errorMessage);
}

private handleAuthentication(email: string, userId: string, token: string, expiresIn: number) {
    console.log('Handle Authentication');
    const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + +expiresIn * 1000);
    const user = new User(email, userId, token, expirationDate);
    this.user.next(user);
}
}
```

The auth.component.ts

```
@Component({
        selector: 'app-auth',
        templateUrl: './auth.component.html',
        styleUrls: [ './auth.component.css' ]
    })
    export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {
        email = '';
        password = '';

    isLoginMode = false;
    isLoading = false;
    error: string = null;
    success: string = null;

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    onSwitchMode() {
        this.isLoginMode = !this.isLoginMode;
    }

    onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
        if (!form.valid) return;

        const email = form.value.email;
        const password = form.value.password;

        let authObs: Observable<AuthResponseData | string>;

        this.isLoading = true;
        if (this.isLoginMode) {
            authObs = this.authService.login(email, password);
        } else {
            authObs = this.authService.signUp(email, password);
        }

        authObs.subscribe(
            (responseData) => {
                this.success = 'Authenticated!';
                this.isLoading = false;
                console.log('Navigating to recipes');
                this.router.navigate([ '/recipes' ]);
            },
            (errorMessage) => {
                this.error = errorMessage;
                this.isLoading = false;
            }
        );

        form.reset();
    }

    onHandleError() {
        this.error = null;
    }

    onHandleSuccess() {
        this.success = null;
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is why the navigation to recipes does not occur until the 2nd successful login.

I can manually navigate by clicking a link on a header component but the navigation should occur, right?

I know it has something to do with the take operator but I can't guess what it is.

Thanks in advance.